# I'm developing an application in Flutter that connects to NASA's APOD API and I'm having an error asking the user for permission

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

The application has a button that the user clicks and calls a DatePicker so that he selects the date he wants, based on the date the application returns the image of the day from the APOD API along with the title, description and 2 buttons, the Download and Share, I'm having problems with this Download button, because when the user clicks on it the _requestPermission() method is called, but this method is not working, it does not appear to approve or deny the permission it automatically denies the permission without even asking to the user, I need help with these methods, here is the code of the methods that are called when the user clicks the download button:

```
Future<String?> _getDownloadsDirectory() async {
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if (directory != null) {
      final downloadsDirectory = '${directory.path}/Downloads';
      return downloadsDirectory;
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _requestPermission(String imageUrl) async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      status = await Permission.storage.request();
      if (!status.isGranted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          const SnackBar(
            content:
                Text('É necessário permitir o acesso para salvar a imagem.'),
          ),
        );
        return;
      }
    } else if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text(
              'A permissão de acesso ao armazenamento foi permanentemente negada.'),
        ),
      );
      return;
    }

    final result = await _getDownloadsDirectory();
    if (result != null) {
      _downloadImage(imageUrl, result);
    }
  }

  void _downloadImage(String imageUrl, String directoryPath) async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));
    final imageBytes = response.bodyBytes;

    const fileName = 'imagem-do-dia.jpg';
    final filePath = '$directoryPath/$fileName';
    final file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(imageBytes);

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text('Imagem salva em $directoryPath'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Please can anyone help me as this is the first app I am developing.
It is worth remembering that I have already added the following permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml file and the version of Android I am running the application on is Android 13 and I have already made the necessary imports:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Just a note, you have tagged iOS but there is are no permissions to read/write external storage on iOS. You can save the file in your apps sandbox documents directory and then either expose this folder to the device "files" app or provide an "export" function that uses `UIpickerViewController` to allow the use to save the file.